# Should I create a new entity for just one (string) field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

Suppose I have an entity, for example:

**Person**

```
-id
-name
-address
-phone
```

And then I want the person to have something that is a string and that may be repeated a lot of times for each person, for example the neighborhood, this is what I think I should do:

**Person**

```
-id
-name
-address
-phone
-idNeighborhood
```

and create a new table

**Neighborhood**

```
-id
-name
```

And of course, idNeighborhood is a foreign key to the id of Neighborhood.

Now, what I was thinking is that I will have to make JOINS every time (let's say I will use the neighborhood in 90% of the cases that I want to use some Person), so, is this wrong?:

**Person**

```
-id
-name
-address
-phone
-neighborhoodName
```

in which I will save the name of the neighborhood, but of course, will be repeated a lot of times (in the other case I would repeat a lot of IDs... so...)..

Also, in my particular case, Neighborhood will never grow, it will always have a name, that's why I think it's better to do this, but I am not really sure..
The only thing that I think of a disadvantage is that I can't make an index of neighborhood and then it will be slower, or not?

Comment: Why do all the EF people think joins are the devil?

Comment: Also, why would a person have more than one neighborhood?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I never said that the a person would have more than one neighborhood, but one neighborhood would have lots of people.. And it is not that joins are devil, it's just that in every case I will have to make JOINS everywhere..

Comment: "Repeated a lot of times for each person" is ambiguous at best. If a person only has one neighborhood, your first design is much better. Your fear of joins is puzzling. If you're literally worried about writing the join more than once, create a view. Conserving keystrokes is a terrible excuse for poor design and/or storing redundant data.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm curious what "EF people" means?

Comment: @WW. Entity Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question about what you want to model.  You should model things in your database that are relevant to the problem you are trying to solve with your system.

Are you interested in neighbourhoods as an entity of their own?

Some reasons you would want to make a neighbourhood table:-

- You end up adding additional attributes to the neighbourhood (say, city or state)
- You end up having two neighbourhoods with the same name, that are actually different (so they need an identity beyond just their name)
- You are worried about storage requirements and you have relatively few neighbourhoods and lots of people (the id will be smaller in size)
- You want to control the master list of neighbourhoods that can be used (people only select from an existing neighbourhood and can't just enter any old thing)

Note that you could apply all this same logic to the name column as well.  But you would only do that if your database was *about* people's names, the same way as you should make a neighbourhood column if modelling neighbourhoods will help with the problem you are solving.

Comment: Thanks! That was really useful, but one more question here: let's say I will do a lot of queries filtering by neighborhood, for example get all the people that are in XX neighborhood, then, the ID case will be faster, won't it? Or can I make an index of the varchar field (the name of the neighborhood in the second case)?

Comment: If you want to find everyone in a specific neighbourhood the ID will be faster because it'll be smaller and therefore less IO, etc.  If you want to do neighbourhood like '%blah%' then it's probably faster to have it in the person table directly.  I wouldn't base my decision on this performance aspect unless you think you're going to have so many rows it's really important. In that case, do some tests.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on your requirement.if you need to display neighbourhood's details like NAME, PROFESSION etc. In your app, the its better to use the first approach i.e create a entity with required attributes.

If you really do not need those details anywhere about your neighbourhood and you just need the name, you can go with your second approach